# Java libraries dependencies

Tags: java

What is the easiest way to see the libraries dependencies in Java project (eclipse)?
I am using Spring MVC and Hibernate so right now there are a lot of jar files and I even do not remember which one of them are responsible for what.

Answer (score 3):

check out  tattletale.

```
http://www.jboss.org/tattletale
```

Answer (score 1):

See them how?

If you're using maven, use the [dependency plugin's](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) `dependency:tree` to get a hierarchical representation of what depends on what.

If you're not, ew; manual management of transitive dependencies sucks! You can use something like [Dependency Finder](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/) or [JDepend](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html) to provide similar info.

Comment: Please refrain from questioning or discussion in answers. Asking for clarification or otherwise from the OP should be done in comments on the question.

Comment: @Kröw … I shall travel back in time 11 years (when SO was a different place) and undo the damage I have done.

Comment: @Kröw My first attempt at resolving the timeline failed miserably and resulted in a world lead by insects. I have gone back twice again; the current state of the world is the result--it's messed up, but at least we're not insect food until *after* we're dead, once again.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but to start with you can right-click the project (in Eclipse) and look at `Properties` -> `Java Build Path`. The `Libraries` tab should list what libraries you're using on your build path. (But you probably knew that.)

If it's a simple standalone project, you could of course always remove a library and see what interesting new errors pop up ;-)

For more complicated projects with interdependencies, it can take quite a bit of fiddling to get all your dependencies right. I generally recommend setting up a "core" project which holds (and exports) most of your third-party JARs (better yet, use [user libraries](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/buildpath/ref-preferences-user-libraries.htm), and putting that project on the build path of your other projects.

Edit after reading your comment: Ah, gotcha... you might be interested in the [Plug-in Dependency Visualisation](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/incubator/dependency-visualization/index.php) incubator project then - haven't used it myself but it sounds like it could do what you're after. Hope that helps!

Comment: As I said I am using spring and hibernate which need many thrid-party jars. So I want some plugin that will show which jar depends on other one.

Comment: Thank s for your reply. It seems that its really that I need but I can't figure out how to view the current project's dependencies. Does anybody know how to make PDE dependency visualisation show the specific project's dependencies?